# Why is my C++ program only printing one character?

Tags: c++

This program is suppose to generate passwords and compare  to what the user inputed, if they match it breaks the while loop and outputs the user's input, but for some reason, the generated passwords are just one characters. I am new to C++, I just started like last Friday.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string Password, Passwords;

    cout << "Enter a password: ";
    getline(cin, Password);
    sleep(.7);
    system("clear");

    while(Password.compare(Passwords)!= 0)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x <= Password.length(); x++)
        {
            for (char Alpha = 'a'; Alpha <= 'z'; Alpha++)
            {
                if(Alpha == 'z')
                {
                    Alpha = 'a';
                }
                for(int I=0; I <= 10; I++)
                {
                    Passwords = Alpha + I;
                    system("clear");
                    sleep(.7);
                    cout << Passwords <<endl;
                }

            }

        }


    }

    cout << "Password found: " << Passwords <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish, but the reason your `Passwords` is a single character is because you set it to a single character: `Passwords = Alpha + I;`

Comment: Also as a matter of style, in C++ we tend to make variable names lower case. So use `password` instead of `Password`.

Comment: `sleep` takes an `unsigned int` parameter, so `.7` will be converted by rounding toward zero, and you sleep zero seconds.

Comment: Also, don't do this: `for (char Alpha = 'a'; Alpha <= 'z'; Alpha++)` because it assumes a lot about characters that might not be true. It *usually* works, but don't get used to doing that. If you want to iterate over the letters, make a string like `abcde....xyz` and iterate over that.

Comment: @Adam have you ever seen a compiler/platform where `char` in range `0-127` is not ASCII encoded?

Comment: what do you expect `Passwords` to be after this line `Passwords = Alpha + I`?

Comment: @bolov What i want to do is get an input from the user and after generate what the user inputed, am just trying to practice, I'm all self taught my teachers are  books

Comment: @bolov yes, EBCDIC. Even if it works *now* and *in English*, it's a pattern that breaks when you apply it in other languages. It's also explicitly discouraged in pretty much every text about working with characters. Testing for equality is fine, but `<` and `>` will bite you eventually.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed can you rephrase this: "after generate what the user inputed". It's unclear what that means.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed I have no idea what you mean

Comment: @AhmedMohamed Give an example: what the user inputs and what you generate and output

Comment: @Adam There's nothing wrong with the for loop of alphabets, it's actually better than the way you're thinking

Comment: @AhmedMohamed you are wrong.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed [edit] your question please with an example of input and output or I'm voting to close as *unclear what you are asking*

Comment: @Adam What I'm trying to do is something similar to math. Lets say you have an equation like 2x+5=10, then you will solve for x and plug the result of x in the x position and try to match both side with the number 10.

Comment: @bolov I want to make a program that will do for loops and get compares the results of the for loop to the inputed word, then when it gets a match it breaks the loops

Comment: @AhmedMohamed **example** please. Maybe it's a language barrier, maybe you don't have the necessary terminology to explain what you want, maybe I just don't understand you, so just give a concrete example

Comment: @bolov      example:                                                                                                                     Enter a word: star                                                                                                                         while loop, for loops, if statements,                                                                                                                 cout << "Generated your word " << star <<endl;

Comment: @AhmedMohamed that is not an example. that is again an explanation. An example would be: User inputs `foo` I check if `foo` equals to `bar` and output `wrong password`

Comment: @bolov if you play with codes, then you will understand what am saying, it's just comparing generated words  with user input, if they match then print out word found

Comment: @AhmedMohamed how do you generate them? What are the generated words?

Comment: @bolov this is like the third time I'm trying to get help from this site, but I don't get it. I want to work for the NSA in the future, but I can't without know something like c++

Comment: @bolov you generate the passwords using the for loop of alphabets, but you first check the length of user input and just generate random words, until you hit the user input

Comment: @AhmedMohamed I am here, making huge efforts to understand you. And yet you stubbornly refuse to give an example to illustrate what you mean.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed was it so hard?

Comment: @AhmedMohamed your code and the explanations you gave are completely different from what you want to do (your last comment): generate random words of the size of the user input.

Comment: @AhmedMohamed Nowhere in the code and in your comments is mentioned *random* until now

Comment: @bolov do you see the part for( char Alpha = 'a'; Alpha <= 'z'; Alpha++)

Comment: @bolov that's the part is suppose to generate random words, it generates the alphabets, but that's it, i want it to generate a words, am just a 17 years old still in high school so thats why you cant understand me, maybe

Comment: @bolov compile and run the program and see for yourself

Comment: `for( char Alpha = 'a'; Alpha <= 'z'; Alpha++)` that has absolutely nothing to do with random.

Comment: @bolov It's suppose to generate words

Comment: @AhmedMohamed but not random

Comment: I HATE THIS SITE, WHEN YOU NEED HELP, BECAUSE YOU GOT NO ONE ELSE TO TURN TO, YOU JUST GET PEOPLE WHO MAKE FUNNY OF YOUR CODE, THANKS A LOT NOW I HATE C++

Comment: @AhmedMohamed dude chill. **Nobody** made fun of your code. You have to understand that we can't read your mind, and your explanations are very unclear, so it is very hard for us to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: warning: `sleep(.7);` is going to take the floating point value 0.7,and turn it into an `unsigned int` as expected by `sleep`. `int` is a whole number and can't handle fractions, so everything after the decimal point will be discarded. 0.7 will become 0 and you get `sleep(0)` which will be much shorter than expected. Try `usleep(700000)` which uses microseconds or [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) which is a portable library call, but requires a bit of reading to get right.

Comment: I added a solution to your problem with a working ideone program and a little explanation for your actual question about 1 char. Hope it helps. **We are here to help each other**. You need to understand that sometimes you make wrong assumptions, you think that what is obvious for you is obvious for everyone. For instance no one could tell from your code that you were trying to generate random words. If you would have simply explained that you would have gotten help faster. Also not getting an answer on some site is no reason whatsoever to hate a language.

Comment: @bolov am sorry, it's just that I do have no sources of help other than this site, and its seems like I don't get an from it

Comment: Start doing online tutorials. Even better start with a [good book]. If you can afford, hire someone to tutor you. And come here with a clear explanation of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a long back and forward in the comments, the OP explained what was his purpose. To generate random words of the same size as input and stop when it matched the input.

This code does what you want. It's in `c++14` so you need a recent compiler and to set the `c++14` option. Please note the actual use of *random*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;

class RandomCharGenerator {
private:
  static std::string s_chars_;

private:
  std::random_device rd_{};
  std::default_random_engine r_eng_{rd_()};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> char_dist_{
      0, static_cast<int>(s_chars_.size())};

public:
  RandomCharGenerator() = default;

  auto getRandomChar() -> char { return s_chars_[char_dist_(r_eng_)]; }
  auto setRandomString(std::string &str) -> void {
    std::generate(std::begin(str), std::end(str),
                  [this] { return this->getRandomChar(); });
  }
};

std::string RandomCharGenerator::s_chars_ = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

auto main() -> int {
  RandomCharGenerator rand_char;

  auto input = std::string{};

  cin >> input;
  auto generated = std::string(input.size(), ' ');

  do {
    rand_char.setRandomString(generated);
    cout << generated << endl;
  } while (input != generated);

  cout << "We generated what you input" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For input longer than 4 characters it takes a long time to generate the input.

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/hEL3Lw)

---

To understand why you had only 1 char in your `Passwords`:

`Passwords = Alpha + I;`

`Alpha` is a `char`, `I` is an `int`. Their sum is an `int`. This is converted to `char` when assigning to `Passwords` which is a `string`. So `Passwords` is now a string composed of only one char.

It's not clear what that actual line of code was supposed to do, so can't tell you what would have been the fix. Maybe you meant to append to `Passwords`. Then you should have written `Passwords += Alpha + I`.

Comment: I added the example, read it, and tell me how I can make my code run like that one, without using array

Answer (score 0):

The code below is an example of what I am trying to make. I did not make the code below, am just giving you and example of what am trying to do in the code above

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password;
    string Generated;

    cout << "Password to find: ";
    cin >> password;

    char Alpha[]={'a'-1,'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a'};

    while( password.compare(Generated) != 0 )
    {

    Alpha[0]++;
    for(int x=0;x<password.length();x++)
    {
       if (Alpha[x] == 'z'+1)
            {
                Alpha[x] = 'a';
                Alpha[x + 1]++;
            }
    }


    Generated=Alpha[password.length()-1]; 

    for(int i=password.length()-2;  i>=0  ;  i-- )
        Generated+= Alpha[i]; 

        system("clear");

        cout << "Trying: "<< Generated << endl; 
    }

    system("clear");
    sleep(1);
    cout <<"Access Granted: "<< Generated << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```